# System Alert wrong word wrap when using localization strings

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, localization

I got the wrong word wrap when iPhone system alert about permission access.

[image: iphone alert with wrong word wrap]

I use localization string files to input strings.

[image: InfoPlist.strings]

[image: NSCameraUsageDescription]

Can someone help me?

Comment: May you can put one more space between `camera` and `to`, but I don't recommend it :D

Comment: This is interesting, would love to see an answer for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the permission string has bad grammar that makes wrong word-wrapping.
After adding "**to**" into this string, the wrapping will be right.
The original string is

> XXXXXXXX needs access camera to scan QR code.

The final string is

> XXXXXXXX needs to access camera to scan QR code.